# Visual Studio 2012 issues opening solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I open my solution in Visual Studio, the source files I had opened in the editor don't automatically reopen. Is there an option or setting to remember this?

Comment: This question is probably best asked on Superuser, this site focuses on programming questions.

Comment: I'm using 2010 and it remembers.  I doubt they removed that feature; maybe some of the auxiliary files that sit in the same directory as your solution are messed up...

Comment: I'd try temporarily renaming YourSolution.suo and maybe YourSolution.vssscc (then restart VS).  It appears the latter is source-control related, so maybe not that one.

Comment: Welcome. This question is off topic. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I didn't realize it was a duplicate.  This has been driving me crazy for days!!